# managed property migration from jsf 1.2 to 2.1

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am new in JSF and I am looking for answer for few question connect with managed property.

I am working with very old code, and I try to update it.

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.example.Bean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>serviceLocalizator</property-name>
    <value>#{serviceLocalizator}</value>
  </managed-property>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>market</property-name>
    <value>#{param['market']}</value>
  </managed-property>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>produktId</property-name>
    <value>#{param['produkt.id']}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

At the bean class is setter for market and getter for product, market is part of another class.

```
private SomeClass daneIn;

public void setMarket(Long market) {
    this.daneIn.setMarket( market );
}

private SomeClass2 produkt;

public  SomeClass2 getProdukt() {       
    return produkt;
}
```

For `productId` and `serviceLocalizator` there is no setter and getter.
There is more properties like 'market' connected with 'daneIn'.

Can anybody explain why:

1. When I remove `<managet-property>` I have null pointer exception for `ServiceLocalizator`, although I invoke static method. What should I read to understand it?
2. Why faces-config use bracket[], instead of dot? Is it connect with POST or GET?
3. Can I use `@ManagedProperty` for 'market' and other properties from daneIn? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** By "when I remove" I assume you're removing the managed property defined for ServiceLocalizator. Since there is no instruction to inject a property, that variable will be null. Using it will result in a NPE.

**2)** The bracket notation is used for various purposes, including the one that covers your case. You can obtain the value of a map by its key, but here you're obtaining the value of the `'produkt.id'` element with brackets since the value used as key contains one or more periods. If you remove the period, you can use `#{param.produktid}` too. (Thanks [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) for the directions in this one)

**3)** You have to declare the property you want to inject with the annotation and provide a setter.

```
public class YourBean {

    //Also, you can use #{param['market']} as the value of the ManagedProperty        
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.market}")
    private Long market;

    public void setMarket(Long market) {
        this.market = market;
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer is not complete wrt point 2. `#{param.market}` works as good in both `@ManagedProperty` and `<managed-property>`. The reason is something entirely different than the base being a `Map`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info to learn more about it.

Comment: @BalusC I'm still a young padawan in JSF :). Still learning. More than updating I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @BalusC Always learning a lot from your tips, hints and answers. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Is it possible not to create field market in the MyBean and use market field from SomeClass represented by daneIn, as it was with <managed-bean> in faces-config?

Comment: The @ManagedProperty annotation is associated to fields. You won't be able to annotate the setter if that's what you have in mind. Please note that you can still use the faces-config approach if required.

Comment: I thought rather use '@ManagedProperty' annotation for SomeClass daneIn, use '@ManagedBean', '@ViewScoped' for SomeClass and '@ManagedProperty' for market field inside SomeClass. Maybe should I use <f:viewParam> instead of '@ManagedProperty'? Sorry if I tangle, I am completely new with JSF and I got thrown in at deep end.

Comment: Indeed, that's a good alternative. Both options are valid, you just have to find the one that suits you the most. And don't worry... I'm rather new too but don't tell anyone :D.

Comment: @k.nieszporek Glad to help. Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem (Green tick below the answer's score).